# Using REGEX to find keywords

Tags: regex, vb.net, keyword

Hey all I have the following *badwords* that I want to check to see if they are in a string that I am passing:

```
Private Function injectionCheck(queryString As String) As Integer
    Dim badWords() As String = {"EXEC", "EXECUTE", ";", "-", "*", "--", "@",
                                "UNION", "DROP", "DELETE", "UPDATE", "INSERT", "MASTER",
                                "TABLE", "XP_CMDSHELL", "CREATE", "XP_FIXEDDRIVES", 
                                "SYSCOLUMNS", "SYSOBJECTS"}
    Dim pattern As String = "\b(" + Regex.Escape(badWords(0))

    For Each key In badWords.Skip(1)
        pattern += "|" + Regex.Escape(key)
    Next

    pattern += ")\b"

    Return Regex.Matches(queryString, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count
End Function
```

For the pattern I get the following:

```
\b(EXEC|EXECUTE|;|-|\*|--|@|UNION|DROP|DELETE|UPDATE|INSERT|MASTER|TABLE|XP_CMDSHELL|
   CREATE|XP_FIXEDDRIVES|SYSCOLUMNS|SYSOBJECTS)\b
```

Which looks correct to me. But every time I call it I get **0** as the response to this:

```
Dim blah As Integer = injectionCheck("select * from bob where something = 'you'")
```

So what am I leaving out that needs to be there since the above should not return *0* - It should return *2* since both * and **'** are used that should not be used.

Comment: The string does not match the pattern. The problem is with `\b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan to match words as whole words, but the keywords may start/end with non-word characters, you might get into a similar trouble. The word boundary meaning depends on the context: `\b--\b` will match in `X--X` but not in `, --,`.

You need an unambiguous boundary matching. Use lookarounds `(?<!\w)` as leading and `(?!\w)` as a trailing word boundary.

Implement the changes as shown below:

```
Dim pattern As String = "(?<!\w)(" + Regex.Escape(badWords(0)) ' <== HERE

For Each key In badWords.Skip(1)
    pattern += "|" + Regex.Escape(key)
Next

pattern += ")(?!\w)"  ' <== AND HERE
```

Comment: Nice one, Wiktor. Thanks!